# eclipse / android / java - cant reference class from jar file in libs

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jar

OK, so I made a jar file, using the eclipse export feature, on one of my projects, let's call it X.

So X.jar has a single class in it, M.class.

I took this jar and put it into the libs/ folder of another project.

When I do

```
M m = new M()
```

it tells me it can't find M, and offers to import it from the package it's in. When I accept that import, it tells me the import cannot be found.

Now, what's confusing (or at least frustrating) is that if I export the jar with M.java instead of M.class, it works - but I need the jar to not be recompiled in the new project, hence why I was hoping to use the class file and not the source.

Comment: are you added that jar to the build path...

Comment: @NoName yes, I have the exact same setup as when I use the source code in the jar. If the jar contains the .java file, it works, and if the jar contains the .class file, it doesn't let me reference that class.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of placing the jar file in the lib folder, try adding it to the build path.

In eclipse:

```
right click on the project -> Build Path -> Configure Build path... -> Add External JARS
```

In IntelliJ:

```
Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S -> Libraries -> new(Plus Sign)
```